# Internet not working

Tags: router, internet, troubleshooting, networking, power-over-ethernet

I have this types of network in my office. Recently we have moved to new i BSNL internet. 
My problem is when i bypass router and connect poe cable to computer internet is working but when i put router after poe and connect my office computers and mobile internet not working it showing limited connectivity.

[image]

Please help

Comment: Sadly, consumer-grade equipment is off-topic here.  You can try asking on [su].